# Can't figure out why this isn't working...returns no results I guess

Tags: php, mysql

```
<?php
$sql = 'SELECT gamedate, gametime, homeschool, visitorschool FROM my_table WHERE WEEKOFYEAR(gamedate)=WEEKOFYEAR(NOW()) ORDER BY gamedate';
$result = mysql_query($sql, $link);

if (!$result) {
echo "DB Error, could not query the database\n";
echo 'MySQL Error: ' . mysql_error();
exit;
if(mysql_num_rows($result)>0) {
?>

<table style="width: 300px; padding: 0; margin-left: -16px;" cellpadding="7px">
<tbody>
<tr><td valign="top"><img src="images/cobrasschedule.png"/></td></tr>
<?php
    mysql_data_seek($result, 0);
    $day = ' '; 
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    if (date('l, F d, Y', strtotime($row['gamedate'])) !== $day) {
    $day=date('l, F d, Y', strtotime($row['gamedate']));

?>
<tr>
    <td colspan="2" style="background-color:#D3BC9A; color:white;text-transform:uppercase; padding-left:25px;"><strong><?= $day?></strong></td>
</tr>
<?php } ?>
<tr>
<?php if ($row['sporttype'] == 'Baseball'): ?>
<td colspan="2" style="background-color:#D3BC9A; color:white;text-transform:uppercase; padding-left:25px;"><strong>BASEBALL</strong></td>
<?php elseif ($row['sporttype'] == 'MBasketball'): ?>
<td colspan="2" style="background-color:#D3BC9A; color:white;text-transform:uppercase; padding-left:25px;"><strong>MEN'S BASKETBALL</strong></td>
<?php elseif ($row['sporttype'] == 'Equine'): ?>
<td colspan="2" style="background-color:#D3BC9A; color:white;text-transform:uppercase; padding-left:25px;"><strong>EQUINE</strong></td>
<?php endif; ?>
</tr>
<tr>
<?php if ($row['homeschool'] == 'Virginia Intermont College - VA'): ?>
<td><p style="text-shadow: none; margin-bottom: -7px;"><strong><?php echo $row['homeschool'];?>vs.</strong><br ><?php echo $row['visitorschool'];?></p></td>
<?php else: ?>
<td><p style="text-shadow: none; margin-bottom: -7px;"><?php echo $row['visitorschool'];?>@<br ><?php echo $row['homeschool'];?></p></td>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php if ($row['homescore'] != ' ' and $row['homeschool'] == 'Virginia Intermont College - VA'): ?>
<td><p style="text-shadow: none; margin-bottom: -7px;"><?php echo $row['homescore'];?><br ><?php echo $row['visitorscore'];?></p></td>
<?php elseif ($row['homescore'] != ' ' and $row['homeschool'] != 'Virginia Intermont College - VA'): ?>
<td><p style="text-shadow: none; margin-bottom: -7px;"><?php echo $row['visitorscore'];?><br ><?php echo $row['homescore'];?></p></td>
<?php elseif ($row['score'] != ' '): ?>
<td><p style="text-shadow: none; margin-bottom: -7px;"><?php echo $row['score'];?></p></td>
<?php elseif ($row['score'] == ' ' and $row['homescore'] == ' '): ?>
<td><p style="text-shadow: none; margin-bottom: -7px;"><?php echo $row['gametime'];?></p></td>
<?php endif; ?>
</tr>
<?php
$day=date('l, F d, Y', strtotime($row['gamedate']));
}
}
?>
</tbody>
</table>

<?php
} else {?>
<span style="vertical-align:top;margin-left:-16px;padding:0;"><img src="images/cobrasschedule.png" border="0"/></span>
<?php
 echo "Schedule is not available.";
}
mysql_free_result($result);
?>
```

I have this same code working in another place and when I run the query in phpMyAdmin it returns 5 rows. But, when I run this on the website it always says "Schedule is not available."

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You are connected to the correct database right? `echo  mysql_db_name($result);`

Comment: no errors?  same exact database connection and query?

Comment: Are you sure that you're connecting to the same database? try to check error reporting and eventually set it to E_ALL. Also, mysql is deprecated, use mysqli instead!

Comment: briosheje - I have been out of the loop when it comes to programming for about 5 years now and I keep seeing the notices for the depreciation of the mysql but I'm not quite sure how to implement the mysqli - do I just replace my mysql with mysqli? Do I need to have a mysqli database? Thanks for the heads up. I just wasn't sure how it worked so I was using what I know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did not close off the error check:

```
if (!$result) {
   echo "DB Error, could not query the database\n";
   echo 'MySQL Error: ' . mysql_error();
   exit;
} // <-- This is missing
if(mysql_num_rows($result)>0) {
```

Therefore the `else` of "Schedule not available" is the `else` to `if(!result) {`. In other words, if the query was successful it is going to print "Schedule not available"

Comment: Thank you so much! I've been working on a build for two weeks with very little sleep and just missed it...COMPLETELY!!!

Answer (score 2):

Aren't you just missing a `}` here?

```
if (!$result) {
echo "DB Error, could not query the database\n";
echo 'MySQL Error: ' . mysql_error();
exit;   // <-- expected `}` here
if(mysql_num_rows($result)>0) {
```

You should really improve your code style. Use a proper IDE.